# Method 'setLenient' of GsonBuilder not found in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, jira-plugin

I am trying to create a Jira plugin which consumes a REST web service using Retrofit and  RxJava2. I created a prototyp of the rest client in a "normal" java programm with the following pom.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>adapter-rxjava2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is the creation of the retrofit client:

```
public ClientService() {

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request originalRequest = chain.request();

                Request.Builder builder = originalRequest.newBuilder().header("Authorization", Credentials.basic(username, password));

                Request newRequest = builder.build();
                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        }).build();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

        Retrofit retro = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(API_URL).client(okHttpClient).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()).build();

        stmdApi = retro.create(StammdatenServiceApi.class);
    }
```

The prototype works as expected.

Now I migrated this prototype into my jira plugin with the following pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.stmd</groupId>
    <artifactId>stmd-import-new</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-2</version>

    <organization>
        <name>company</name>
        <url>http://www.company.com</url>
    </organization>

    <name>retrofit-proto</name>
    <description>test of retrofit</description>
    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.context.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.activation.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>adapter-rxjava2</artifactId>
            <version>${retrofit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>${retrofit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
            <version>${retrofit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>${rx.java.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jira-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                    <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                    <jvmArgs>-Xms2g -Xmx4g</jvmArgs>
                    <applications>
                        <application>
                            <applicationKey>jira-software</applicationKey>
                            <version>${jira.version}</version>
                        </application>
                    </applications>

                    <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                    <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                    <instructions>
                        <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>

                        <!-- Add package to export here -->
                        <Export-Package>
                            de.westlotto.jira.stmd.api,
                        </Export-Package>

                        <!-- Add package import here -->
                        <Import-Package>
                            android.*;resolution:=optional,
                            org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional",
                            org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional",
                            *;version="0";resolution:=optional
                        </Import-Package>

                        <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered -->
                        <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>atlassian-spring-scanner</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scannedDependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-external-jar</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </scannedDependencies>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <jira.version>7.13.1</jira.version>
        <amps.version>8.0.0</amps.version>
        <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.13</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
        <javax.activation.version>1.1.1</javax.activation.version>
        <rx.java.version>2.2.8</rx.java.version>
        <retrofit.version>2.5.0</retrofit.version>
        <retrofit.osgi.version>2.5.0_1</retrofit.osgi.version>
        <spring.context.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.context.version>
        <gson.version>2.8.5</gson.version>
        <!-- This property ensures consistency between the key in atlassian-plugin.xml and the OSGi bundle's key. -->
        <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</atlassian.plugin.key>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

This time there seems to be a dependency problem with the Gson lib. The method `setLenient()` of `GsonBuilder`  in the line

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
```

is not being resolved. Everything else is working just fine. I used the same dependencies in both poms as far as it is possible but the error still exists. I don't have an idea where to look now. IntelliJ is just not resolving this method.

I tried re-importing all dependencies and deleted the project cache but both did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you build project by Maven from command line?

Comment: No, it fails with `cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   method setLenient() [ERROR]   location: class com.google.gson.GsonBuilder`

Comment: Can you check your dependency tree and see if there's any conflict and duplicate dependency.

Comment: For what it's worth: I had a similar issue (but not with a plugin, it's a standalone app), and bumping Gson to `2.8.6` fixed the issue

Comment: @jmm That fixed it for me as well. Never had an issue before when it was set at 2.4 but it all of a sudden started happening. I upgraded to `2.8.5`, which is what Android Studio suggested, and it worked find after a rebuild. Thanks for the tip!